# How to allow circular navigation of items in a QComboBox?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

The Qt desktop app I'm writing contains a QCombobox in the UI (made with Designer). After I select the QCombobox, I can change the selected item by scrolling the mouse wheel, or by pressing the up/down arrows on the keyboard. That all works fine.

When navigating using the keyboard down arrow, for example, when I reach the bottom item in the list, the down arrow no longer changes the selected item. I understand that this is the expected behavior.

But for this particular QComboBox I'd like to be able to keep pressing the down arrow after reaching the final item in the list, and "wrap" back to the first item, so I can continue to cycle through the items. I have studied the documentation for QComboBox at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html and for QAbstractItemModel at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html, but I could not discover any way to achieve what I want here.

Ideally I'd prefer a solution that works for keyboard arrow navigation, for mouse scroll wheel navigation, and for any other UI gesture that might try to activate the "next" or "previous" item in the QComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this solution, but I'm guessing that it's right by intuition.
I think you need to do:

1. Override [`keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#keyPressEvent) to detect up and down arrows.
2. If the down arrow is pressed, check if it's the last index using `currentIndex() const` function, compared to the size of the combo box itself.
3. If so, change the current index to the first one using `setCurrentIndex(int index)`.
4. Do the same for up arrow if you reached the first index.

P.S. As `currentIndex()` returned the index after pressing, this might make it jump from the penultimate index to the first one. Thus, I suggest using a private boolean member to be toggled when the condition is met for the first time.

I hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Thanks. This approach would probably work, along with changing mouseWheelEvent() too. But I'm still hoping for a higher level approach. atm I'm looking at overriding QListView::moveCursor(...) which sounds like it could be the best approach. But it's not working yet.

Comment: @ChristopherBruns If it works, please mark it as an accepted answer. In addition, I searched for more robust solution but in vain. I hope you'll find a better one if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The full solution to this problem has a few different aspects.

1. When the `QComboBox` is expanded to show all the items, an elegant semantic solution is to override the `QAbstractItemView::moveCursor()` method. This part of the solution does not require low level event handlers because `moveCursor()` encapsulates the concept of "next" and "previous". Sadly this only works when the `QComboBox` is expanded. Note that the items are not actually activated during navigation in this case, until another gesture like a click or enter occurs.
2. When the `QComboBox` is collapsed to show one item at a time (the usual case), we have to resort to the low level approach of capturing each relevant gesture, as sketched in the answer by Mohammed Deifallah. I wish Qt had a similar abstraction here analogous to `QAbstractItemView::moveCursor()`, but it does not. In the code below we capture key press and mouse wheel events, which are the only gestures I'm aware of at the moment. If other gestures are also needed, we would need to independently implement each one. Because the Qt architects did not generalize the concepts of "next" and "previous" for these cases the way they did for `QAbstractItemView::moveCursor()`.

The following code defines a replacement class for QComboBox that implements these principles.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt


# CircularListView allows circular navigation when the ComboBox is expanded to show all items
class CircularListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    """
    CircularListView allows circular navigation.
    So moving down from the bottom item selects the top item,
    and moving up from the top item selects the bottom item.
    """

    def moveCursor(
        self,
        cursor_action: QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.CursorAction,
        modifiers: Qt.KeyboardModifiers,
    ) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        selected = self.selectedIndexes()
        if len(selected) != 1:
            return super().moveCursor(cursor_action, modifiers)
        index: QtCore.QModelIndex = selected[0]
        top = 0
        bottom = self.model().rowCount() - 1
        ca = QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.CursorAction
        # When trying to move up from the top item, wrap to the bottom item
        if index.row() == top and cursor_action == ca.MoveUp:
            return self.model().index(bottom, index.column(), index.parent())
        # When trying to move down from the bottom item, wrap to the top item
        elif index.row() == bottom and cursor_action == ca.MoveDown:
            return self.model().index(top, index.column(), index.parent())
        else:
            return super().moveCursor(cursor_action, modifiers)


class CircularCombobox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        view = CircularListView(self.view().parent())
        self.setView(view)

    def _activate_next(self) -> None:
        index = (self.currentIndex() + 1) % self.count()
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)

    def _activate_previous(self):
        index = (self.currentIndex() - 1) % self.count()
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QKeyEvent) -> None:
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self._activate_next()
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            self._activate_previous()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QtGui.QWheelEvent) -> None:
        delta = event.angleDelta().y()
        if delta < 0:
            self._activate_next()
        elif delta > 0:
            self._activate_previous()
```